# Disable compiling in Visual Studio 2010 for Virtual Directories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, windows-server-2008, compilation, virtual-directory

I have a web site running on Windows 2008 R2/IIS 7.5/.NET 4.0.

Recently in order to debug a problem that was local to the server I installed Visual Studio 2010 on the web server. When I Clicked File->Open->WebSite-> [Local IIS] (my site) it opened the site just fine but wouldn't set a debug point as it stated that "no symbols had been loaded for for this document". Every other time I have run into this problem it has been because the project/solution wasn't built in debug mode. I did publish to this server from my local machine and in debug mode.

So I figured I would just build the solution again in debug mode. However, the web server has virtual directories that contain user uploaded files that I obviously don't want Visual studio to compile and it blows up if it even tries.

My question is how do I get Visual Studio 2010 to ignore the virtual directories when compiling without having to remove them from the web site? OR How do I publish to the web site in such a way that the .pdb file works correctly and the debug symbols are loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do it if you do Build Website. You may want to choose Build Page instead.

But I really think your problem is related to debugging more than to build.

Make sure you have all .pdb files in the \bin folder not just .dll and try Debug, attach to process, and select all processes that are named w3wp (if you don't see it, there are checkboxes to show process from all users, check them).

Answer (score 0):

From project properties (windows), change the virtual path to just a slash (/).